# Dollar sign US phone number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I just need to know why the dollar sign is needed at the end of the regex for validating US phone numbers

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {

return (/^(1)?(\s)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/).test(str) 

}
console.log(telephoneCheck("551-555-5555"));
```

Comment: `$` denotes the end of a string.

Comment: That doesn't validate the number, it just checks whether it fits a certain pattern. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is start of string and `$` is end of string.

Therefore we want to match only this string, not a substring within a larger string.

Fully explained:

- `^` assert the start of the string
- `(1)?` zero or one "1"
- `(\s)?` zero or one whitespace character
- `(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` 3 digits in () or 3 digits
- `[\s-]?` zero or one whitespace or "-"
- `\d{3}` 3 digits
- `[\s-]?`zero or one whitespace or "-"
- `\d{4}` 4 digits
- `$` end of string

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eE33FM/1)

- With:

[image]

- Without:

[image]

Comment: Great explanation cheers!